# Add up BigDecimals in Map by matching with keys from another Set

Tags: java, lambda, collectors

I have a Map with sales numbers divided by year:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> sales_by_year = new TreeMap<>();
sales_by_year.put(2012, BigDecimal.valueOf(19283));
sales_by_year.put(2013, BigDecimal.valueOf(24832));
sales_by_year.put(2014, BigDecimal.valueOf(19562));
sales_by_year.put(2015, BigDecimal.valueOf(21879));
sales_by_year.put(2016, BigDecimal.valueOf(23587));
sales_by_year.put(2017, BigDecimal.valueOf(28756));
```

and a list of which years I want to add up these sales:

```
Set<Integer> years = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2012, 2013, 2014}));
```

and I want to write a lambda to combine these years into one `BigDecimal`. I wrote this:

```
BigDecimal sales_for_timeframe = sales_by_year.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(a -> years.contains(a.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
        .values().stream()
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

System.out.println(sales_for_timeframe);
```

and it works. But is this the most efficient way? This solution:

1. Converts the map into a stream
2. Filters the map
3. Collects it back into a new map
4. Converts the new map's valueSet into a stream
5. Reduces the values to a single `BigDecimal`

Is there a way to reduce the number of steps? Will doing so increase efficiency? Or is this the best solution?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your version isn’t bad, if you remove the obsolete step of collecting into a new `Map`. Just replace `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)) .values().stream()` with `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten it slightly:

```
BigDecimal sum = years.stream()
    .map(y -> sales_by_year.getOrDefault(y, BigDecimal.ZERO))  
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: I liked your first version better, as an alternate to my answer.

Comment: Yes, both are good :) I liked your `getOrDefault` to avoid null.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be more efficient, because:

- No intermediate collection
- Iterating the smaller `years` set, instead of the larger `sales_by_year` map

```java
BigDecimal sales_for_timeframe = years.stream()
        .map(yr -> sales_by_year.getOrDefault(yr, BigDecimal.ZERO))
        .filter(bd -> bd.signum() != 0) // prevent unnecessary adds (optional)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

In an earlier edit, [answer by jspcal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50558078/5221149) had this alternate implementation, entirely using method references:

```java
BigDecimal sales_for_timeframe = years.stream()
        .map(sales_by_year::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: If you want to avoid unnecessary `add` operations, replace `.reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)` with `.reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)`…